# How to use awesome with angular2-webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, font-awesome

I copy the https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter app. I want to use awesome, but it's not working.

In **webpack.common.js**,   add:

```
loaders: [
     { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass'] },
     { test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000' },
     // Bootstrap 4
     { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' }, ...]
```

and **vendor.ts**

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-loader';
import 'font-awesome-loader';
```

The query and bootstrap 4 is fine, but awesome icon is not. Why?

Comment: perhaps you can add at top of app.style.css  like this @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

Comment: I add it in the root css file, but import it met 403 . How to add it from local npm packages ?Since i have added .

Comment: is it in your node_modules ? then 
import 'font_awesome/dist/css/font_awesome'; (Path to css) or else in assets 
import './assets/css/font_awesome';

Comment: yes, in node_modules file.path is : "/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" .. How to write it in src/assets file ? thanks .

Comment: you are using webpack so you cant get access to node_modules from src directory , so if you have vendor file then please include the below line import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome'

Comment: or if you want it in your local assets , this will happen during compiling  , in webpack config you need copy from node_modules to assets with CopyWebpackPlugin

Comment: I have vendor file . and put ` import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome'`,but there is en err --`ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome' in '/Users/hushuming/Desktop/a/qsap-web-module/src'
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 21:0-40`

Comment: can you share vendor file ? it should work , it is working cool for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124761/discussion-between-kery-hu-and-code-buster).

Answer (score 0):

I've made following

**Changes in webpack.common.js**

```
/*
 * add to Webpack Plugins
 */
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

...

/*
   add to rules 
*/
  rules: [

    /*
     * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
     * Replace templateUrl and stylesUrl with require()
     *
     * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
     * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
     */
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: [
        '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
        'awesome-typescript-loader',
        'angular2-template-loader'
      ],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    },
  ],

  /*
    In the plugins section ad
  */
  plugins: [
     ...
  /*
   * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
   * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
   *
   * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
   */
  new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
  ...
  ]
```

**In the component** I include font-awesomem then

```
@Component({
    selector:       'intro',
    template:    template
    styles:         [require('../../assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')        ]
})
```